# Loading images every half second in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm pretty new to lua coding. In my intro page I want to load a different image every 0,5 second while a background music is playing. Here is my code (non working):

```
function carica_indice()
   im=math.random(1,4)
   schermataMenu=display.newImage(immagine[im],W,H)
   volte=volte+1
end

function menuprincipale()

 media.playSound( "sigla1.mp3" )
immagine={"firstscreen.png","firstscreen1.png","firstscreen2.png","firstscreen3.png","firstscreen4.png","firstscreen5.png"}

schermataMenuGroup=display.newGroup()

while volte<32 do
 schermataMenu=display.newImage(immagine[im],W,H)
 timer.performWithDelay(500,carica_indice())
end
end
```

Comment: What are you doing with `schermataMenu`?

Comment: Hi Etan, schermataMenu is a background image i want to change every half second to make the intro page more appealing. It is part of a display group  (together with a textTitle and a button Play) that i remove when i tap on "Play" and go to the game screen.

Comment: In the code here you assign values to it but you don't use it anywhere. You also didn't tell us what is happening that shouldn't be or what isn't happening that should be so we don't know what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

`timer.performWithDelay(500,carica_indice())`

here you are actually calling the function by using those parentheses.
Pass the function as an argument like this:

timer.performWithDelay(500, carica_indice)

timers don't actually stop your code from executing so the while loop will continue to add a lot of timers before the first 32 would fire.
I'm guessing volte is some sort of limit? for that you can ask the timer to repeat a number of iterations instead of the while loop like this:

```
changeBkg = timer.performWithDelay(500, carica_indice, 32)
```

you can cancel the timers now, when the user hits play by:

```
timer.cancel(changeBkg)
```

Comment: Great suggestion Etan! I put 32 in the iteration parameter and it works fine! Thanks a lot!:)